# pygame crashes when double clicking on screen

Tags: python, crash, pygame

Whenever I was trying to make a snake game , this is still incomplete, whenever my snake collides with boundary it goes to the next screen a prints

> you suck try again

but if I double click anywhere on the pygame window it crashes sometimes.

Tthe number of left clicks are more than just 2 but in the end it still crashes after clicking a while.

What must I do to fix this as this issue is not there for the initial screen where I play with the snake.

The code I used is given below:

```
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()
font = pygame.font.Font(None,25)
def mess(msg,color):
    screen_text = font.render(msg, True , color)
    display.blit(screen_text , [(w/2) - 50 , h/2] )
score = 0
w = 800
h = 600
display = pygame.display.set_mode((w,h))
pygame.display.update()
red = (255,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
yellow = (255,255,0)
bye = False
xpos = w/2
ypos = h/2
xch  = 0
ych  = 0
b    = 10
while True:
    wa = random.randrange (10,700)
    ha = random.randrange (10,500)
    if wa%10 == 0 and ha%10 == 0:
        break

time = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 10
up = False
side = False
lenth = 10
while not bye:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w and up == False:
                 ych = -b
                 xch = 0
                 up = True
                 side = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_s and up == False:
                 ych = +b
                 xch = 0
                 up = True
                 side = False

            if event.key ==pygame.K_d and side == False:
                 xch = +b
                 ych = 0
                 side = True
                 up = False

            if event.key == pygame.K_a and side == False:
                 xch = -b
                 ych = 0
                 side = True
                 up = False
    if xpos == wa  and ypos == ha:
        lenth = lenth + 10
        while True:
            wa = random.randrange (10,700)
            ha = random.randrange (10,500)
            if wa%10 ==0 and ha%10 == 0:
                break

        score = score + 10
    if xpos == w - 10  or xpos == 0 or ypos == h - 10 or ypos == 0:
        xch = 0
        ych = 0
        display.fill(black)
        mess("You suck Try again!",red)
        pygame.display.update()
        break

    xpos = xpos + xch
    ypos = ypos + ych
    time.tick(FPS)

   display.fill(white)
   display.fill(red , rect=[xpos,ypos,10,10])#snake
   display.fill(yellow ,rect=[xpos + 0.41 , ypos +10 ,10 , lenth])#bady
   display.fill(black, rect=[wa,ha,10,10])  #food
   pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Next time please take your time to make your question readable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will totally fix your problem. But having while loops like this with no sleep in them can cause your program to take up all of your CPU power, which may cause your program to crash. A way to fix this is changing this code...

```
while True:
    wa = random.randrange (10,700)
    ha = random.randrange (10,500)
    if wa%10 ==0 and ha%10 == 0:
        break
```

To this...

```
wa = random.randrange(1,70)*10
ha = random.randrange(1,50)*10
```

This removes the while loop all together and still gives to a number divisibly by 10 between 10 and 700, and 10 and 500.

Comment: I tried it , but the problem still remains , thanks though this bit of code is much more efficient and useful to me .

Answer (score 0):

When your snake gets out of the screen, this if statement is executed:

```
if xpos == w - 10  or xpos == 0 or ypos == h - 10 or ypos == 0:
    xch = 0
    ych = 0
    display.fill(black)
    mess("You suck Try again!",red)
    pygame.display.update()
    break
```

So after drawing some text to the display and calling `pygame.display.update()`, you call `break` which ends your `while` loop.

So your game does not crash, it just ends.

Comment: I know that's what its supposed to do it should just end , but in the next screen if try clicking somewhere randomly on the screen it should do nothing but instead after few clicks it just crashes (Window becomes unresponsive) which its not supposed to do .